# Python GAE: raised ValueError(Unpaired high surrogate) with json.loads only on production server

Tags: json, google-app-engine, python-2.7, urlfetch

On GAE with Python, I'm using urlfetch to fetch a json string from Flickr. When I try to load that string with json.loads on the production server the exception "raised ValueError(Unpaired high surrogate)" is thrown.

When I try to json.loads the string in the development console, it loads into a dict as expected (see below). I have successfully loaded several other json strings from Flickr with the same code. There is something about the json string below that throws the ValueError exception ONLY on the production server.

```
import json

s = """{"photo":{"id":"191019103", "secret":"d7a8bb95bc", "server":"72", "farm":1, "dateuploaded":"1153079847", "isfavorite":0, "license":"1", "safety_level":"0", "rotation":0, "originalsecret":"d7a8bb95bc", "originalformat":"jpg", "owner":{"nsid":"13968020@N00", "username":"\ud800dc80 jgraham", "realname":"", "location":"", "iconserver":"38", "iconfarm":1}, "title":{"_content":"By the Year 2000 All Our Food Will be in the Form of Tiny Pills"}, "description":{"_content":""}, "visibility":{"ispublic":1, "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0}, "dates":{"posted":"1153079847", "taken":"2006-07-15 14:31:16", "takengranularity":"0", "lastupdate":"1282690106"}, "views":"984", "editability":{"cancomment":0, "canaddmeta":0}, "publiceditability":{"cancomment":1, "canaddmeta":0}, "usage":{"candownload":1, "canblog":0, "canprint":0, "canshare":1}, "comments":{"_content":"18"}, "notes":{"note":[]}, "people":{"haspeople":0}, "tags":{"tag":[{"id":"1207251-191019103-2909", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"Birmingham", "_content":"birmingham", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-77552", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"Bullring", "_content":"bullring", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-463", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"Abstract", "_content":"abstract", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-1174", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"Architecture", "_content":"architecture", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-141", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"Blue", "_content":"blue", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-2194948", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"i500", "_content":"i500", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-11820", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"Explore", "_content":"explore", "machine_tag":0}, {"id":"1207251-191019103-3254511", "author":"13968020@N00", "raw":"utata_feature", "_content":"utatafeature", "machine_tag":0}]}, "urls":{"url":[{"type":"photopage", "_content":"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/jgraham\/191019103\/"}]}, "media":"photo"}, "stat":"ok"}"""

print json.loads(s) #prints dict
```

Comment: This is a really unique problem! I've narrowed it down to `json.loads('{"username":"\\ud800dc80 jgraham"}')`. I copied the source and compared to `json` version 2.0.9 and they are for all intents and purposes the same, so this error comes from elsewhere. Still digging.

Comment: Here is a good answer about why it's failing: https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/issues/62#issuecomment-13996448

Answer (score 0):

sudo pip install simplejson==3.6.5

```
import simplejson
simplejson.loads('{"":"\\ud800"}')
```

I had the same problem with low surrogates (\udfb6)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed for Python 2.7.7 and above.

http://bugs.python.org/issue11489

https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v2.7.7/Misc/NEWS

However, as of the 11th of March 2016, Google App Engine is running Python  2.7.5 in production, which doesn't have patch 11489 to the json module.

I spoke to the GAE support team about this issue, and they have raised a Google Public Issue Tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12823

In the meantime, using the [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) module instead of the standard json module, as suggested by [mihaicc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648904/mihaicc), looks like the best solution. I tested simplejson version 3.8.2 and it both worked on GAE and did not produce the error.

Answer (score 0):

GAE Standard's Python 2 runtime [migrated from 2.7.5 to 2.7.12 in June 2017](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/enhancing-the-python-experience-on-app-engine), so this should no longer be an issue. You can test on https://shell-hrd.appspot.com/ :

```
Google App Engine/1.9.86
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 12 2019, 11:33:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang google3-trunk (trunk r361749)]

>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"":"\\ud800"}')
{u'': u'\ud800'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big json file with one record per line and don't mind missing some lines, you can just ignore those lines.

```
grep -v "\\\\ud" file.json > file2.json
```